# AWS lambda to delete default VPC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3, vpc

New to cloud, Can anyone help to correct this code

This module is to list the regions and delete the complete default vpc via a lambda function.

Getting below error while testing this:
Syntax error in module 'lambda function': unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Please help on this
 Removed other function like vpc, sc as the block looks very big here in the post just added the igw for understanding..

Need assistance

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    #for looping across the regions
    regionList=[]
    region=boto3.client('ec2')
    regions=region.describe_regions()
    #print('the total region in aws are : ',len(regions['Regions']))
    for r in range(0,len(regions['Regions'])):
        regionaws=regions['Regions'][r]['RegionName']
        regionList.append(regionaws)
    #print(regionList)
    #regionsl=['us-east-1']
    #sending regions as a parameter to the remove_default_vps function
    res=remove_default_vpcs(regionList)


    return {
        'status':res
    }

def get_default_vpcs(client):
  vpc_list = []
  vpcs = client.describe_vpcs(
    Filters=[
      {
          'Name' : 'isDefault',
          'Values' : [
            'true',
          ],
      },
    ]
  )
  vpcs_str = json.dumps(vpcs)
  resp = json.loads(vpcs_str)
  data = json.dumps(resp['Vpcs'])
  vpcs = json.loads(data)

  for vpc in vpcs:
    vpc_list.append(vpc['VpcId'])  

  return vpc_list

def del_igw(ec2, vpcid):
  """ Detach and delete the internet-gateway """
  vpc_resource = ec2.Vpc(vpcid)
  igws = vpc_resource.internet_gateways.all()
  if igws:
    for igw in igws:
      try:
        print("Detaching and Removing igw-id: ", igw.id) if (VERBOSE == 1) else ""
        igw.detach_from_vpc(
          VpcId=vpcid
        )
        igw.delete(

        )
      except boto3.exceptions.Boto3Error as e:
        print(e)


def remove_default_vpcs():
    for region in res:
    try:
      client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = region)
      ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = region)
      vpcs = get_default_vpcs(client)
    except boto3.exceptions.Boto3Error as e:
      print(e)
      exit(1)
    else:

      for vpc in vpcs:
        print("\n" + "\n" + "REGION:" + region + "\n" + "VPC Id:" + vpc)
        del_igw(ec2, vpc)

print(completed)
```

Comment: Thanks yes it is indentation issue and it is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me a code indentation issue. Please try with this

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  # TODO implement
  #for looping across the regions
  regionList=[]
  region=boto3.client('ec2')
  regions=region.describe_regions()
  #print('the total region in aws are : ',len(regions['Regions']))
  for r in range(0,len(regions['Regions'])):
      regionaws=regions['Regions'][r]['RegionName']
      regionList.append(regionaws)
  #print(regionList)
  #regionsl=['us-east-1']
  #sending regions as a parameter to the remove_default_vps function
  res=remove_default_vpcs(regionList)


  return {
      'status':res
  }

def get_default_vpcs(client):
  vpc_list = []
  vpcs = client.describe_vpcs(
    Filters=[
      {
          'Name' : 'isDefault',
          'Values' : [
            'true',
          ],
      },
    ]
  )
  vpcs_str = json.dumps(vpcs)
  resp = json.loads(vpcs_str)
  data = json.dumps(resp['Vpcs'])
  vpcs = json.loads(data)

  for vpc in vpcs:
    vpc_list.append(vpc['VpcId'])  

  return vpc_list

def del_igw(ec2, vpcid):
  """ Detach and delete the internet-gateway """
  vpc_resource = ec2.Vpc(vpcid)
  igws = vpc_resource.internet_gateways.all()
  if igws:
    for igw in igws:
      try:
        print("Detaching and Removing igw-id: ", igw.id) if (VERBOSE == 1) else ""
        igw.detach_from_vpc(
          VpcId=vpcid
        )
        igw.delete(

        )
      except boto3.exceptions.Boto3Error as e:
        print(e)


def remove_default_vpcs():
  for region in res:
  try:
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = region)
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = region)
    vpcs = get_default_vpcs(client)
  except boto3.exceptions.Boto3Error as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)
  else:

    for vpc in vpcs:
      print("\n" + "\n" + "REGION:" + region + "\n" + "VPC Id:" + vpc)
      del_igw(ec2, vpc)

print(completed)
```